# embed variable as subject for a html link

Tags: wordpress, email, mailto

I have a html code like this on a Wordpress page:

```
<a href="mailto:test@wb.nl?subject=taalfouten">test@wb.nl</a>
```

What I want to achieve is to add the page-title or url as a variable in the email subject. Is that at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
<?php 
 $pagename = get_query_var('pagename');  
   // If a static page is set as the front page, $pagename will not be set. Retrieve it from the queried object

   if ( !$pagename && $id > 0 ) {  
    $post = $wp_query->get_queried_object();  
    $pagename = $post->post_name;  
 } ?>

 <a href="mailto:test@wb.nl?subject='<?php echo $pagename ?>'">test@wb.nl</a>
```

this is for displaying page title which is worked for me, Similarly for URL

```
 $pageurl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
 <a href="mailto:test@wb.nl?subject='<?php echo $pageurl ?>'">test@wb.nl</a>
```

Comment: This worked perfect for me. I am using the genesis framework so I implemented it through a hook like this:

    `<script>
<?php $pageurl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
</script>
<a href="mailto:test@wb.nl?subject=<?php echo $pageurl ?>">test@wb.nl</a>`

Answer (score 1):

First set

```
<?php $pagename = get_query_var('pagename'); ?>
```

e.g. in your *header.php* file.

In your template for your page you can use something like

```
<a href="mailto:test@test.com?subject=<?php echo $pagename; ?>">test@wb.nl</a>
```